# How do I use emacs to show me the source for a python function?

Tags: python, emacs

With (very) minimal setup, how do I use emacs 23.3.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin) to show me the code for a function I am interested in?

As an example, I want to see the code for the superclass's 'db_type' in:

```
def db_type(self, connection):
    return super(EnumField, self).db_type(connection)
```

I am using the django framework, however I do not believe that is relevant.

It would be nice if I could type M-. and have it bring up a list of auto-generated tags, for instance, rather than having to manually grep code myself or update tags.

Comment: Haven't used it myself, but [Jedi](https://github.com/davidhalter/jedi) and it's [emacs implementation](http://tkf.github.io/emacs-jedi/) are pretty popular

Answer (score 0):

try [emacs for python](https://github.com/gabrielelanaro/emacs-for-python), although that's not considered as minimal setup IMO.

Comment: Yeah, 99% of my time I'm NOT in python, so a minimal setup is very much wanted. :/